# What does ~0 mean in this code?

Tags: c++

What's the meaning of ~0 in this code?
Can somebody analyze this code for me?

```
unsigned int Order(unsigned int maxPeriod = ~0) const
{
    Point r = *this;
    unsigned int n = 0;
    while( r.x_ != 0 && r.y_ != 0 )
    {
        ++n;
        r += *this;
        if ( n > maxPeriod ) break;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Although most of the answers below will lead you to believe that `~0` will yield the highest value of the unsigned type you're assigning to, such behavior is not guaranteed. Use `-1` instead.

Comment: @avakar Would ~0u work instead? Why not?

Comment: @avakar It seems that -1 would have a corresponding problem in a non-twos-complement environment.

Comment: @Mark B, no, conversion from `int` with value `-1` to any unsigned type is defined to result in the maximal value for that unsigned type. @user168715, in this particular case, `~0u` would work, as it would result in the maximal value for `unsigned int`. Note that it might not work if `maxPeriod` was `unsigned long` (and in this case it wouldn't work in practice, not only due to the letter of the standard).

Comment: @academicRobot, there is not undefined behavior, there is implementation defined behavior for `~0` and well-defined behavior for `-1`.

Comment: @academicRobot, additionally, the fact that `n > UINT_MAX` will always yield false does not mean the code is broken, it means that the precondition of `a.Order()` is that `a` has a finite order.

Comment: Tagged C and C++ but the example is C++ specific.

Comment: @Clifford, indeed, though the question "what’s the meaning of `~0`" is valid in both languages.

Comment: I think your keyboard must be broken. I removed all the extra question marks. In English, we only use *one* question mark to indicate a question.

Comment: @user168715 yes, `~0u` is equivalent here. But not if the type were changed to `unsigned long`, so using `-1` avoids the need to match the suffix to the declared type

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`~0` is the bitwise complement of `0`, which is a number with all bits filled. For an unsigned 32-bit int, that's `0xffffffff`. The exact number of `f`s will depend on the size of the value that you assign `~0` to.

Comment: Actually, `0` is of type `int` and therefore the `~` operator is applied to a signed value. The result of such operation is, if I'm not mistaken, implementation defined.

Comment: @avakar: That's because the C spec doesn't assume that the machine uses 2s-complement arithmetic. OTOH, I've *never* used a machine that wasn't a 2s-complement system, and I can't think offhand of any processor sold on the general market today that implements 1s-complement integer math. Maybe there are some, but they're like hen's teeth.

Comment: I believe this is well defined. The relevant part of the standard (C89, 3.3.3.3, "Unary arithmetic operators") says: "The expression ~E is equivalent to (ULONG_MAX-E) if E is promoted to type unsigned long , to (UINT_MAX-E) if E is promoted to type unsigned int ."

Comment: @Thanatos: The "integer promotions" applicable in this case do not cause an `int` to be promoted to either `unsigned long` or `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Thanatos, what @caf said. Nobody is arguing about the value `~E` for unsigned `E`. But the discussion is about `~0`, and `0` is a `signed int`.

Comment: @Donal Fellows, there still are mainframes that use ones' complement. But even if there weren't, and `~0` was guaranteed to have the value -1, the use of `~0` in place of `-1` should be discouraged -- why would one want to express the value -1 with `~0` when `-1` is a much more direct approach?

Comment: Really, it doesn't matter, since they're both crappy ways of getting the value that code seems to want.  In C there are macros, and in C++ there is numeric_limits.

Comment: @avakar: Are you *sure* that the compiler isn't understanding `-1` as (`unary -` and `1`)? Well, before deciding it's a constant anyway of course, but that applies to `~0` too.

Comment: @Donal Fellows, yes, the grammar makes `-1` two tokens. When I said "more direct approach" I meant for humans. @Dennis Zickefoose, I have no mental problem with using -1. It is guaranteed to work, it can be used in generic code (unlike macros) and it's a constant expression (unlike `numeric_limits::max()`).

Answer (score 19):

It's the one complement, which inverts all bits.

```
 ~  0101 => 1010
 ~  0000 => 1111
 ~  1111 => 0000
```

Answer (score 9):

As others have mentioned, the `~` operator performs bitwise complement. However, the result of performing the operation on a signed value is not defined by the standard.

In particular, the value of `~0` need not be `-1`, which is probably the value intended. Setting the default argument to

```
unsigned int maxPeriod = -1
```

would make `maxPeriod` contain the highest possible value (signed to unsigned conversion is defined as an assignment modulo `2**n`, where `n` is a characteristic number of the given unsigned type (the number of bits of representation)).

Also note that default arguments are not valid in C.

Comment: Perhaps it's just a choice of expression but it's not exactly the semantics of the application of `~` that is implementation defined, the operation must always complement each bit in the binary representation of the operand. What isn't defined (I don't believe that it is even implementation defined) is exactly which binary representation (e.g two's complement, ones' complement, signed magnitude, etc.) is used for each integer type. This means that it's not defined what the resulting numeric value of performing ~ on an object of signed integer type will be even though the mechanism is defined.

Comment: @Charles Bailey, yes indeed the operation is defined to perform one's complement. However the fact that representation of signed values is not defined means, that the value of `~0` is not defined either. And I'm starting to doubt myself, maybe you're right and it is not even implementation defined.

Comment: @Charlie: I think that the result of bit-wise inversion is defined because each bit that was 0 is now 1 and each bit that was 1 is now 0.  What is not defined is what the value is when interpreted as a number; different binary representation systems will interpret the bitwise inverted value differently.

Comment: Perhaps it's not the value -1 that was intended, but a bitfield with all bits 1.

Comment: The value of `~0` is implementation-defined (this is a bit stronger than "not defined")

Answer (score 4):

It's a binary complement function.

Basically it means flip each bit.

Answer (score 4):

It is the bitwise complement of 0 which would be, in this example, an int with all the bits set to 1.  If sizeof(int) is 4, then the number is 0xffffffff.

Comment: If `sizeof(int)` is 4, it is very likely that `0xffffffff` is not a valid `int` value.

Comment: @avakar: Its a perfectly valid int value. In fact, it is -1 in twos-complement systems.

Comment: `0xffffffff` is not -1, it's 4294967295 and if `sizeof(int)==4`, the value will be of type `unsigned int`. Converting this unsigned value to `int` will yield an implementation defined value as this unsigned value is out of range for `int` (yes, on two's complement machines the converted value will be -1).

Answer (score 4):

Basically, it's saying that maxPeriod has a default value of UINT_MAX.  Rather than writing it as UINT_MAX, the author used his knowledge of complements to calculate the value.

If you want to make the code a bit more readable in the future, include

```
#include <limits>
```

and change the call to read

```
unsigned int     Order(unsigned int maxPeriod = UINT_MAX) const
```

Now to explain why ~0 is UINT_MAX.  Since we are dealing with an int, in which 0 is represented with all zero bits (00000000).  Adding one would give (00000001), adding one more would give (00000010), and one more would give (00000011).  Finally one more addition would give (00000100) because the 1's carry.

For unsigned ints, if you repeat the process ad-infiniteum, eventually you have all one bits (11111111), and adding another one will overflow the buffer setting all the bits back to zero.  This means that all one bits in an unsigned number is the maximum that data type (int in your case) can hold.

The "~" operation flips all bits from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0, flipping a zero integer (which has all zero bits) effectively gives you UINT_MAX.  So he basically the previous coded opted to computer UINT_MAX instead of using the system defined copy located in `#include <limits.h>`

Comment: In C++ (question is also tagged C++) I'd go with `#include <limits>` and `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()` instead of `UINT_MAX`; although some implementations (e.g. some versions of xlC) do not inline that function, resulting in an actual function call instead of a constant value compiled in to the binary.  YMMV.

Comment: Edwin, "Since we are dealing with unsigned numbers": `0` is not unsigned, its type is `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the C / C++ differences.  I guess I just reached for the "C" way due to too many years of C code.

Answer (score 0):

In the example it is probably an attempt to generate the UINT_MAX value.  The technique is possibly flawed for reasons already stated.

The expression does however does have legitimate use to generate a bit mask with all bits set using a literal constant that is type-width independent; but that is not how it is being used in your example.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, ~ is the bitwise complement operator (sometimes also referred to as bitwise not). It's a unary operator which means that it takes a single input.

Bitwise operators treat the input as a bit pattern and perform their respective operations on each individual bit then return the resulting pattern. Applying the ~ operator to the bit pattern will negate each bit (each zero becomes a one, each one becomes a zero).

In the example you gave, the bit representation of the integer 0 is all zeros. Thus, ~0 will produce a bit pattern of all ones. Even though 0 is an int, it is the bit pattern ~0 that is assigned to maxPeriod (not the int value that would be represented by said bit pattern). Since maxPeriod is an unsigned int, it is assigned the unsigned int value represented by ~0 (a pattern of all ones), which is in fact the highest value that an unsigned int can store before wrapping around back to 0.